# What could cause a computer to run slow without any evident changes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, ghostscript.net

Over the past couple months, I have been working on an application which converts PS files to PNG using Ghostscript.net, and then merges these into another PDF document.

There are 100+ PS files which get converted to PNG. This is done with Ghostscript.net and is multithreaded. I have not posted any code, because I don't believe my issue is necessarily code related. I have tested this program hundreds of times over the past couple months without issue. Yesterday I went to test it again, and the multithreaded portion was going incredibly slow. The CPU usage hovers around 100% during this portion, but the output is taking exponentially longer to produce.

I attempted to run an older, more stable, version of this application, and have the same issue. I also reduced the number of files it is running to just 1 PS file, and it still runs incredibly slow. Anything over 4 PS files ends up "timing out" or throwing an exception after attempting to run for about 5 minutes.

I ran my application on other computers, with less memory and processing power, and the other computers run it without issue.

My question is basically, what could have happened with my machine to cause these issues? Where is a good place to start investigating. I am using a work computer, so my level of access is limited. When I ran the program with only 4 PS files, the conversion process took a very long time, but the code that is executed after seems to have no performance issues. I am using a Windows 7 machine with an Intel core i7 and 16GB of RAM.

**EDIT:** So I have identified the issue (and think it makes this question more relevant to this forum). Normally, when using the Ghostscript application to convert .ps to .pdf, a temporary file is created for each output file. Once the application is terminated, the temp files created in the session are deleted.
I went digging into my temp files in the AppData\Temp\ (after a little more research, I now know that Ghostscript will use the TEMP environment variable to determine where these files will be stored) and noticed that there were a bunch of _teXXXX.tmp files in there (a little over 65,000). I also noticed that these _teXXXX.tmp files were all in groups of a few hundred with the same creation date/time.

Apparently, when using the Ghostscript.net dll, these files do not get disposed of. For a while, you would not see a slowdown, because when the dll would request a temp file name, it would just continue to count up and return a block of file names. After months of testing, it must have run out of available names in the naming convention it was using, causing it to slow down at first (searching through the whole range to find an unused name), and then finally cause it to stop running all together.

After I deleted all of these temp files, my application ran normally.

The Ghostscript.NET Processor object has a "Dispose()" method, but this did not seem to solve the issue. As I'm doing these conversions in a multithreaded environment, I am going to try to run them in a single threaded manner and see if the issue still occurs. I am submitting this as a bug, as I can't seem to find a solution for this at the moment. For now, I will just implement some code and delete these files myself after the run is complete.

Comment: This is an interesting, well-written question, but it's probably not on-topic for SO (since it's not about programming) and could also be described as "too broad."  Just letting you know not to take it too hard if it gets closed on you.  Might be a good question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: I thought about that, but didn't know where else to turn. Any suggestions of other forums that might be able to assist with this? Edit: Just saw your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how the notification system works on this, but if you're interested, I discovered the issue. The post edit explains what was going on.